# Catching SIGSEGV when triggered by corrupt stack

Tags: c, linux, signals, segmentation-fault, sigaction

I've been working on some buggy code and wanted to install a SIGSEGV handler to get more information about the crash. However, I noticed that my handler is not invoked.

I've been looking for a reason and it seems it has to do with a corrupt stack pointer value (it's not getting masked for sure). Here's some proof-of-concept code I wrote up to verify:

```
static void catch_function(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *cntxt)
{
    puts("handler works");
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_sigaction = (void *)catch_function;
    sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_NODEFER ;

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

    puts("testing handler");
    raise(SIGSEGV);
    puts("back");

    __asm__ (   "xor %rax, %rax\n\t"
                "mov %rax, %rsp\n\t"
                "push 0" 
            );

    // never reached...
}
```

The idea is to set RSP to 0 (invalid offset) and then use it for something. However, this second SIGSEGV will not be caught by the handler but instead terminates the process.

Apparently, invoking the signal handler needs a sane stack pointer to begin with -- but why? Isn't this against the idea of handling signals? Any chance of getting around this?

I'm running Linux version 3.19.0-25-generic.

Comment: @EOF -- thanks; that looks promising. Will post solution when successfull.

Comment: can you try running your program inside valgrind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a solution to the above problem following EOF's comment (using `sigaltstack()` to provide a signal stack on the heap):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __USE_GNU
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

static long long int sbase;

static void catch_function(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *cntxt)
{
    puts("handler works");

    /* reset RSP if invalid */
    ucontext_t *uc_context = (ucontext_t *)cntxt;
    if(!uc_context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RSP])
    {
        puts("resetting RSP");
        uc_context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RSP] = sbase;
    }
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    /* RSP during main */
    sbase = (long long int)&argv;

    stack_t ss;
    struct sigaction sa;

    ss.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
    ss.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    ss.ss_flags = 0;
    sigaltstack(&ss, NULL);  

    sa.sa_sigaction = (void *)catch_function;
    sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_NODEFER | SA_ONSTACK;

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

    puts("testing handler");
    raise(SIGSEGV);
    puts("back");

    __asm__ (
            "xor %rax, %rax\n\t"
            "mov %rax, %rsp\n\t"
            "push %rax\n\t"
            "pop %rax"  );

    puts("exiting.");
}
```

The alternative signal stack is allocated on the heap and registered using `sigaltstack(&ss,NULL)`. Also, the `SA_ONSTACK` flag is set in the `sigaction` struct to enable the alternative stack use for this specific action.

This basically resolves my problem, because now we see an endless stream of `SIGSEGV`s being caught. After all, the above `catch_function()` doesn't do much to fix the invalid stack pointer.  As a solution, I now store the valid stack pointer for the `main()` in `sbase` and use that to restore it in the handler if it's invalid (through manipulation of the saved thread context).

To make all of this work, I also fixed my inline assembly to not just push a value but also pop it back afterwards, so the stack height remains unchanged. For the sake of replicability, I also included the includes this time.